Real-life example of fail by not using equivalent transformation
Solve the equation :
$\sqrt{x}=x-2$
Square it :
$x=(x-2)^2$
Expand :
$x=x^2 - 4x +4$
Everything to the left side :
$x - (x^2 - 4x +4) = 0$
Refine the equation :
$x^2 - 5x +4 = 0$
Factorize :
$(x-1)(x-4) = 0$
Getting roots :
$x =1$ or $4$
There is nothing wrong in any step.
But the answer is not correct.
$x = 4$ is the only solution.
Because the step 'Square it' is not a equivalent transformation.
It is very difficult to make this understandable to ordinary students who have to learn mathematics.
Can you find any real-life example of particular problem (outside of mathematics), like above example ? I mean :
Inference at each step is correct, but the answer is wrong in the end, because one of the inference used was not a equivalent transformation.

https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/814cpi/bertrand_russell_is_the_pope/

I’m voting to close this question because asking for a "real life example" that's not mathematics for a mathematical phenomon you understand is not appropriate on this site. It might be OK on the math education stack exchange.

@EthanBolker I disagree with your characterization of the math question presented.  See my answer.  What the posted question is really asking for is some explanation of what the analysis signifies.  That is, I think that if the OP (i.e. original poster) prints out my answer and shows it to their students, that it will make sense to their students.  So, the analysis in my answer is actually providing a claification of how the logic works.

Actually, the first line is deficient: It should be $\sqrt{x}=x-2\geq 0$, since the square root symbol conventionally represents the unique positive square root.

@TankutBeygu I disagree.  Assuming that this is a problem in real analysis, rather than complex analysis, the original constraint, $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x} = x - 2,~$ is complete as is.  As a direct consequence of the original constraint, one can infer that $~x-2 \geq 0.~$ However, this inference need not be explicitly stated as part of the original constraint.

$A=B$ implies $A^2=B^2$ but $A^2=B^2$ doesn’t imply $A=B.$ This is not obvious and it trips people up. But it’s easy to demonstrate.

You started with an equation, which I will refer to as $~E_1,~$
Then, you took a series of steps, which I will refer to as $~S_1, S_2, \cdots.$
The way that the logic flowed, you have something like
$$E_1 \implies S_1 \implies S_2 \implies \cdots \implies S_5. \tag1 $$
Your analysis was all valid.  There is nothing wrong with the above implications.  The difficulty that you are experiencing is that you are misinterpreting what the implications in (1) above signify.
What they signify is that for any $~x,~$ if $~x~$ satisfies $~E_1,~$ then it must satisfy $~S_5.$  This is a perfectly valid conclusion.
However, the implications in (1) above do not signify that for any $~x,~$ if $~x~$ satisfies $~S_5~$ then it must satisfy $~E_1.~$ Such a conclusion, which is not supported by your analysis, is invalid.
So, although (for example) $~x=1~$ satisfies $~S_5,~$ it does not satisfy $~E_1.$

For illustrative purposes, consider the following simpler example.
$~x = 2 \implies x^2 = 4.$  So, if $~x~$ satisfies the equation $~x = 2,~$ then $~x~$ must satisfy the equation $~x^2 = 4.~$
However, the reverse is not true.  For example, just because $~-2~$ satisfies the equation $~x^2 = 4,~$ does not imply that $~-2~$ satisfies the equation $~x = 2.$

What this all boils down to is that in the original problem, your analysis proved that
if $~x~$ satisfies $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x} = x - 2,$
then $~x~$ must satisfy $~(x-1) ~(x-4) = 0.$
So, the set $~\{1,4\}~$ represents the set of all possible candidate solutions.  This means that no other value of $~x~$ can possibly satisfy the original equation $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x} = x - 2.$
However, you then still have to check each candidate solution manually to see if it satisfies the equation $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x} = x - 2.$

I think OP understands all that, but wants an example of the same logical flaw cropping up in a nonmathematical context.

@GerryMyerson You may well be right.  However, I question this.  I think that the OP's primary concern is educating their students.  See my comment to Ethan Bolker, following the originally posted question.  That is, by printing out my answer and showing it to their students, the students will no longer be confused.
